# $|C(a)|+|C(b)|=p\ge2\ (prime)$ and we have to determine $|C(a) \cap C(b)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have a group $G$ and $a,b\in G$.

$C(x)=\{y\in G |yx=xy \}$. We know that $|C(a)|+|C(b)|=p\ge2\  (prime)$ and we have to determine $|C(a) \cap C(b)|$.

$C(a),C(b)$ are subgroups in $G$ so $C(a) \cap C(b)$ is subgroup too. I don't know what to do next. Can somebody help me,please?

We also have that $C(a) \cap C(b) \subset C(a)$ and $C(a) \cap C(b) \subset C(b)$ but I don't know if that results to $C(a) \cap C(b) \le C(a)$. That would be helpful to use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Hint: the fact that $|C(a)|+|C(b)|$ is prime implies that $|C(a)|$ and $|C(b)|$ are coprime.

Comment: I can't figure if that helps

Comment: As you wrote  yourself, $C(a) \cap C(b)$ is a subgroup of both $C(a)$ and $C(b)$, so what does Lagrange's Theorem tell you?

Comment: We know it is a subset, but we don't know if it's a subgroup.

Comment: You yourself wrote: "so $C(a) \cap C(b)$ is a subgroup too".

Comment: Is a subgroup of G, but we don't know if it's a subgroup of $C(a)$

Comment: Why don't you try and prove that it must e a subgroup of $C(a)$?